# Read csv file and store content in array using python

Tags: python, arrays, csv, sorting, store

i have CSV file as the following:

```
aa , a1, 1, bb, b1, 11, cc, c1, 111
aa2 , a2, 2, bb2, b2, 22, cc2, c2, 222
aa3 , a3, 3, bb3, b3, 33, cc3, c3, 333
```

and I need to take the first three content and store it in array like:
`aa , a1, 1, bb, b1, 11, cc, c1, 111` will become into `['aa a1 1', 'bb b1 11', 'cc c1 111']`

and this my code:

```
import csv

with open('Test.csv') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
    rows = list(csv_reader)
    lines= len(list(rows))

    for line in range(lines):
        i=0
        j=1
        k=2

        for l in range(len(list(rows[line]))):
            t=[]
            t.append(rows[line][i]+rows[line][j]+rows[line][k])
            print(t[0:])
            i+=3
            j+=3
            k+=3
```

Comment: Hello! Nice code. And what is your question?

Comment: Note the code would probably be slightly more readable if you write `for row in lines:` rather than `for line in range(lines):`, and then replace every occurrence of `rows[line]` by simply `row`.

Comment: i want to get each 3 column like aa, a , 1 and store it in as one column until i get this ['aa a1 1', 'bb b1 11', 'cc c1 111']

Comment: with my code i get this error
['aa  a1 1']
[' bb b1 11']
[' cc c1 111']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\kitar\Desktop\oop.py", line 18, in <module>
    t.append(rows[line][i]+rows[line][j]+rows[line][k])
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: i get this solution but for one row and after that be out of range

Comment: What do you want in the end? More exactly what do want to do with lines following the first one?

Comment: i want to sorting it 
sort 'aa a 1' in the first and 'bb...' second and so on

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `for`-loops, it is usually preferable to iterate on the items directly, using for instance `for row in rows:`, rather than on the indices, using for instance `for line in range(lines):`.

Also, note that every time you call `list`, you are building a new list. This can be wasteful. For instance, `lines = len(list(rows))` builds an unnecessary copy of the list `rows`. You could have simply written `nb_lines = len(rows)`.

Since you want to split your list into chunks of 3, you might be interested in reading these:

- [Question: How do you split a list into evenly-sized chunks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-you-split-a-list-into-evenly-sized-chunks);
- [Documentation for `more_itertools.chunked`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#more_itertools.chunked);
- [Itertools recipe: "Collect data into fixed-length chunks or blocks"](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes).

```py
import csv

t = []
with open('Test.csv') as csv_file:
    for row in csv.reader(csv_file):
        t.append([' '.join(row[i:i+3]) for i in range(3)])
print(t)
# [['aa   a1  1', ' a1  1  bb', ' 1  bb  b1'],
#  ['aa2   a2  2', ' a2  2  bb2', ' 2  bb2  b2'],
#  ['aa3   a3  3', ' a3  3  bb3', ' 3  bb3  b3']]
```

We can get rid of the bad-looking extra spaces, [using `str.strip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip):

```py
import csv

t = []
with open('Test.csv') as csv_file:
    for row in csv.reader(csv_file):
        t.append([' '.join([word.strip() for word in row[i:i+3]]) for i in range(3)])
print(t)
# [['aa a1 1', 'a1 1 bb', '1 bb b1'],
#  ['aa2 a2 2', 'a2 2 bb2', '2 bb2 b2'],
#  ['aa3 a3 3', 'a3 3 bb3', '3 bb3 b3']]
```